# How to extract articles with certain words from the RFBR website using a parser in JSON format?

Tags: python, json

I have a code that displays the parser from the RFBR website. The parser itself should be output to JSON and look like this:

```
{
  "Название"
  "Статус"
  "Время окончания приема заявок"
  "Полное описание условий конкурса"
  "Документы" {
   "Формы заявок"
   "Договор и инструкции"
   "Формы отчетов"
  }
 }
```

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import chardet
import xlsxwriter
import re
from datetime import date, timedelta
 
PAGES_COUNT = 100
OUT_FILENAME = 'out.json'
 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
 
 
def get_soup(url, **kwargs):
    response = requests.get(url, **kwargs, verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
    else:
        soup = None
    return soup
 
 
def crawl_products(pages_count):
    urls = []
    fmt = 'https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest?CONTEST_STATUS_ID=-1&CONTEST_TYPE=-1&CONTEST_YEAR=-1&page={page}'
 
    for page_n in range(1, 1 + pages_count):
        print('page: {}'.format(page_n))
 
        page_url = fmt.format(page=page_n)
        soup = get_soup(page_url)
        if soup is None:
            break
 
        for tag in soup.select('.tr .link'):
            href = tag.attrs['href']
            url = 'https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest{}'.format(href)
            urls.append(url)
    return urls
 
 
def parse_products(urls):
    data = []
 
    for url in urls:
        print('product: {}'.format(url))
 
        soup = get_soup(url)
        if soup is None:
            break
 
        for i in soup.find_all("h1"):
            name = i.text
        for j in soup.find_all("main", {"class":"template__main"}):
            for jj in j.find_all("div", {"class":"sfc l-3 mt-5 mb-10 lh-xl"}):
                ja = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', r'', str(jj))
                jo = re.sub(r'\<[^>]*\>', '', str(ja))
                ji = re.sub(r'_', '', str(jo))
                ju = re.sub(r'  ', '', str(ji))
                je = re.sub(r' :', '', str(ju))
                jy = je[13:]
                amount = jy
        rponse = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        sp = BeautifulSoup(rponse.text, "lxml")
        document ={}
        dcs = sp(attrs={"class": "list-in article"})
        for z in dcs:
            document[z.h2.text] = list(z.ol.stripped_strings)
            # document[z.h2.text] = tuple(z.ol.stripped_strings)
 
        # в одну строку с разделителем запятая
        for z in dcs:
            document[z.h2.text] = ', '.join(z.ol.stripped_strings)
        try:
            article = [l.get_text(strip=True) for l in soup.find_all("p") if l.get_text(strip=True).startswith('Условия')]
            art = str(article).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        except:
            article = [l.get_text(strip=True) for l in soup.find_all("strong") if l.get_text(strip=True).startswith('Условия')]
            art = str(article).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        for row in soup.select('td'):
            cols = row.select('td')
            cols = [c.text.strip() for c in cols]
        item = {
            'Название': name,
            'Статус': 'Заявки не принимаются',
            'Время окончания приема заявок': amount,
            'Полное описание условий конкурса': art
        }
        item['Документы'] = document
        data.append(item)
 
    return data
 
 
def dump_to_json(filename, data, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('ensure_ascii', False)
    kwargs.setdefault('indent', 1)
 
    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, **kwargs)
 
 
def main():
    urls = crawl_products(PAGES_COUNT)
    data = parse_products(urls)
    dump_to_json(OUT_FILENAME, data)
 
    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or another one

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import chardet
import xlsxwriter
import re
from datetime import date, timedelta

PAGES_COUNT = 100
OUT_FILENAME = 'out.json'

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


def get_soup(url, **kwargs):
    response = requests.get(url, **kwargs, verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
    else:
        soup = None
    return soup


def crawl_products(pages_count):
    urls = []
    fmt = 'https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest?CONTEST_STATUS_ID=-1&CONTEST_TYPE=-1&CONTEST_YEAR=-1&page={page}'

    for page_n in range(1, 1 + pages_count):
        print('page: {}'.format(page_n))

        page_url = fmt.format(page=page_n)
        soup = get_soup(page_url)
        if soup is None:
            break

        for tag in soup.select('.tr .link'):
            href = tag.attrs['href']
            url = 'https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest{}'.format(href)
            urls.append(url)
    return urls


def parse_products(urls):
    data = []

    for url in urls:
        print('product: {}'.format(url))

        soup = get_soup(url)
        if soup is None:
            break

        for i in soup.find_all("h1"):
            name = i.text
        for j in soup.find_all("main", {"class":"template__main"}):
            for jj in j.find_all("div", {"class":"sfc l-3 mt-5 mb-10 lh-xl"}):
                ja = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', r'', str(jj))
                jo = re.sub(r'\<[^>]*\>', '', str(ja))
                ji = re.sub(r'_', '', str(jo))
                ju = re.sub(r'  ', '', str(ji))
                je = re.sub(r' :', '', str(ju))
                jy = je[13:]
                amount = jy
        rponse = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        sp = BeautifulSoup(rponse.text, "lxml")
        document ={}
        dcs = sp(attrs={"class": "list-in article"})
        for z in dcs:
            document[z.h2.text] = list(z.ol.stripped_strings)
            # document[z.h2.text] = tuple(z.ol.stripped_strings)

        # в одну строку с разделителем запятая
        for z in dcs:
            document[z.h2.text] = ', '.join(z.ol.stripped_strings)
        article = [l.get_text(strip=True) for l in soup.find_all("p") if l.get_text(strip=True).startswith('Условия')]
        art = str(article).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        for row in soup.select('td'):
            cols = row.select('td')
            cols = [c.text.strip() for c in cols]
        item = {
            'Название': name,
            'Статус': 'Заявки не принимаются',
            'Время окончания приема заявок': amount,
            'Полное описание условий конкурса': art
        }
        item['Документы'] = document
        data.append(item)

    return data


def dump_to_json(filename, data, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('ensure_ascii', False)
    kwargs.setdefault('indent', 1)

    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, **kwargs)


def main():
    urls = crawl_products(PAGES_COUNT)
    data = parse_products(urls)
    dump_to_json(OUT_FILENAME, data)

    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code is works. But one moment.

It is necessary that in one of the arrays a sentence with the words "Условия конкурса" be displayed. It is output. But not from all links.

What and where should be corrected?

I need an element of code which extracts from all links article with word  "Условия конкурса" in beginning.